# AS3 save file in accessible location on iOS

Tags: ios, file, actionscript-3, text, save

I have written an app that creates a text file that is then used to populate a document. It all works fine on Android and Windows - the text file saves to an accessible location and can be attached to an e-mail.

On iOS the story is different. I seem to be able to save (I think) the file into the application storage directory, by using the following code.

```
file1 = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("data.txt");
var stream1:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream1.open(file1, FileMode.WRITE);
stream1.writeUTFBytes(string1+"\r\n"+string2);
stream1.close();
```

I say I think it saves, as my popup appears to tell me that the file is saved, so it is at least working through the code. With other directory references the button does nothing.

But I cannot find any way to then navigate to that folder so that I can attach it to an e-mail. I have tried different email clients, different file managers but nothing seems to work. I thought about saving to the iCloud or google Drive, but there does not seem to be the facility to do that in iOS11.

I am sure I cannot be the only person trying to share an app generated text data file through iOS, but I cannot find any ways to do it.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I have no experience with iOS, but it sounds pretty much like access rights problem. It is not impossible that in iOS the app storage location is secure and not accessible from other applications without elevated rights. You should probably scan the device folder tree with your application and save to some common shared location like "Download" or such.

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at Permissions, but unlike Android there is no write to Local Storage permission.

Comment: can you update your question with your read code too since thats where the problem is arising .

Comment: Thanks. I have subsequently discovered that in iOS the sharing of files between apps is not possible. Seemingly it is blocked by the OS.

Comment: Pressed enter too quickly. There is no read code. The idea is that the file is saved to an accessible location and then attached to an e-mail. I have found the message ANE from Distriqt and it seems that will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching, I discovered the Distriqt Message ANE that does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

iOS sandboxes applications so you can't directly access the files of another application.

iOS (and Android) provide mechanisms for sharing data though. On iOS you can use the Mail Composer, Activity and Document Interaction view controllers and on Android via specific Intents.

These mechanisms allow you to "send" data to other applications via user interaction (generally). Your role will be to create the data (image / text / links etc) to share and pass it to the OS to ask the user how to handle the share. Through this mechanism another application can be delivered your data.

This eliminates the need for public access to the data, as the permission to access the data is removed as soon as the mechanism completes.

The [Message ANE](https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.Message) and [Share ANE](https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.Share) we (distriqt) have developed allow AIR developers to access these mechanisms.